# LocalCloseInputStream when second time calling getInputStream with different URLConnection

Tags: android, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am trying to download two apks from my application server consequently  one after another with in different activities using HTTPURLConnection but second time i am getting an empty inputstream. I have dissconted the previous connection before finishing the first activity and also used setUseCaches(false) as per some answers on stackoverflow but still i am facing the problem. I have also checked the log and as i think the problem is the getting LocalCloseInputStream instead of LimitedInputStream,that i was getting when i am trying first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After After a lot of research finally I got the solution. I have just added

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

in very first line of doInBackground function of AsynkTask and its working fine for me.Hope it will help others in future.Thanks.